# Image uploaded from iPhone gets corrupted

Tags: iphone, wcf

I'm trying to take a photo from my iPhone app and upload to a WCF REST service.

I'use the UIImagePickerController to access the camera and assign the new photo to a UIImageView on my view.

Then I use the UIImageJPEGRepresentation to convert it to "real" data.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.2);
```

Then I try submitting a request to my service like this:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setFile:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"imageData"];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

The service receives the data and writes it to the disk on my webserver. But I can't open the image on the server, as Windows tells me the file was corrupted. I'm guessing I need so set some kind of encoding or content type in my iPhone app. I do receive HTTP status code 200 from my service after the upload is through.

I've made a small C# client app just to test the service, and when I upload a photo from my Windows machine using this client everything is fine. So I guess it has to been something I'm missing in y request from the iPhone.

Thanks for reading, and for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you post your interface declarations for WCF?  I'm trying something similar and having troubles.

Comment: i too would be interested in how you solved this on the server side.  I can send from the iphone just fine, but the Stream on my webserivce is always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a ton of approaches I finally got it working using:

```
[request appendPostData:imageData];
```

instead of:

```
[request setFile:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"imageData"];
```